# How to format html output table with multiple regression results?

Tags: html-table, output, regression

I ran 9*6(total of 54) lm regressions similar to y ~ p + u + v +... and now want to format the results of these regressions as one singel html table to be used in word, etc. I am new to making such tables but understand stargazer, huxtable and texreg might be useful. I want my table to include just the coefficient and significance stars of variable p for all 54 regressions, and want the table to look something like this:

[Output][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFd6E.png

I have stored the 54 regression model outputs in a list. 9 and 9 of those models will be each of the 6 3x3 matrices in the table.

I am not allowed to share a sample of the dataset, but i believe any kind of regression result is applicable. As a proxy I suggest using the mtcars dataset and running 54 regressions. I belive that to be the simplest solution.

So far I have tried using stargazer, but have not been able to format the table as wanted.

Comment: `m <- mx(NA, 9, 6); for (row in 1:9) for (col in 1:6) m[row, col] <- results[[row*6 + col - 7]]; as_huxtable(m)`? Adding the significance star is left as an exercise....

Comment: Figured the easiest solution was to just format dataframes with the information i wanted and use huxtable to format a nice table, but thanks anyway. Solved the significance star problem by using an ifelse function